# Monitoring serial port

Tags: windows, monitoring, serial-port, dial-up

I'm using a communications program (Tera Term) to communicate with another computer through a dialup connection. I'll be sending a file with this software, but I would like to monitor the port (like PortMon) to measure the time it takes to transfer the file. Do you know any way of doing it without this software?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling adventurous, you could write your own. There is a Dr Dobbs article [here](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416559) that will tell you how.

Alternatively, you could try a hardware splitter.